# WheelEvent constructor does not work in LockerService

Tags: lightning, locker-service

When trying to create a WheelEvent using its constructor, I was unable to do so, despite the WheelEvent being clearly marked as supported in the [Locker Api Viewer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-viewer).

The issue is reproducible easily by using the [Locker Console](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console):

1. Replace the content of the code editor in the Locker Console by `new WheelEvent('onwheel');`
2. Toggle off Locker and click on Evaluate. Assert that you get `[object WheelEvent]` as a response.
3. Toggle on Locker and click on Evaluate. Assert that you get `Error: Failed to construct 'WheelEvent': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.`.

I'd expect something similar to MouseEvent to happen instead, meaning that you'd get an object representing a MouseEvent (even tho it's not one per se)

I would understand the current behavior if there were some provision in the Locker API Viewer concerning the WheelEvent API, but that's not the case, so I expect the constructor of WheelEvent to works with or without Locker.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. The Locker API Viewer shows WheelEvent as supported. This should probably be reported to Salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed as a bug by Salesforce support through Case#26801396.

ETA for the fix is "Summer 20 patch 12 (Safe Harbor)".